# How does SSIS convert DT_WSTR to DT_STR?

Tags: unicode, ssis

What is the methodology that the SSIS data conversion transformation uses when converting a DT_WSTR to DT_STR? If a character exists in the DT_WSTR which does not exist in the destination code page of the DT_STR, will the mapping fail, or ignore the character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it uses WideCharToMultiByte or something similar.

You control what happens by setting truncation options, see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141679.aspx